# Showing that $\{nz^n\}$ Diverges for $|z| \ge 1$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

**Goal:** I'm looking to verify that everything I've said here is correct.

Let $z \in \mathbb{C}$ satisfy that $|z| \ge 1$.  Consider the sequence $\{nz^n\}$.  I'm trying to show rigorously that this sequence diverges.  Suppose for sake of contradiction it converged to some complex value $A$.

1. Let $\epsilon > 0$.
2. Since this sequence converges, there must be an $N$ s.t. $\forall n \ge N$ we have that $|nz^n - A| < \epsilon$.  Then let $n \ge N$.
3. Then $|nz^n - A| = n|z^n - A/n| \rightarrow n|z^n - 0| = n|z^n|$.
4. Yet $n|z^n| \rightarrow \infty$ since $|z^n| \ge 1$ given our choice of $z$.
5. Then $|nz^n - A| \rightarrow \infty$ implies that $|nz^n - A| \not < \epsilon$, a contradiction.
6. Hence $\{nz^n\}$ is a divergent sequence if $|z| \ge 1$.

Is everything I said here correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an attempted refinement of my own answer:

1. Consider that $\{w_n\} \rightarrow w$ only if $\{|w_n|\} \rightarrow |w|$ for $w, w_i  \in \mathbb{C}$ (of course, the converse needn't hold).
2. Then to demonstrate that $\{nz^n\}$ diverges for any $z \in \mathbb{C}$ that satisfies $|z| \ge 1$, we will show that it cannot be the case that $\{|nz^n|\}$ converges.
3. To see why $\{|nz^n|\}$ diverges, consider that for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have that

   $$
   |nz^n| = n|z^n| = n|z|^n \ge n
   $$

   since $|z| \ge 1$.
4. Hence for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have that the absolute value of $nz^n$ gets successively larger than $1$.  It is hence impossible that $\{|nz^n|\}$ converges, and hence impossible that $\{nz^n\}$ converges either (via $(1)$).

Answer (score 1):

In 3., you stated $n|z^n-A/n|\rightarrow n|z^n-0|$, and, if I'm correct,, you did this because $A/n\rightarrow 0$. But you **cannot** do this because when you take the limit (that is, you use the arrow $\rightarrow$), you have to take the limit of everything that is on the left side, in that case, and you're simply ignoring the terms $n$ and $z^n$ there.

There is a much simpler argument that you can use to prove this, and you basically did it in item 4.

Comment: Thanks for the hint.  I attempted to use it to answer my own question above.  Is this correct?

Comment: @user125104 It's better now. I think you should put your answer in the question, by adding "EDIT:[...your answer, as below...]" at the bottom.